# Any chrome extension developer at here help me to find out why this warning is coming

Tags: codeigniter, google-chrome, warnings

Is there any chrome extension developer at here help me to find out why this chrome console warning is coming...

Chrome console warning : "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type application/json"

My chrome extension popup.html 's code is like this :

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/CI/index.php/api/example/users/format/json?jsoncallback=?",
 {format: "json"},function(data){
    for (var i in data) 
    {
         //alert(data[i].ThreadID);
         document.write(data[i].ThreadAuthorFirstName + " : " + data[i].ThreadTitle );
   document.write("<br />");
    }
});
```

The data which the extension getting from the server is this..

```
[{"ThreadID":"213","ThreadTitle":"Christian Heilmann's talk for the why of HTML5 for games development","ThreadAuthorFirstName":"Suresh kumar"},{"ThreadID":"208","ThreadTitle":"The PHP Switch Statement","ThreadAuthorFirstName":"Suresh kumar"},{"ThreadID":"212","ThreadTitle":"DaVinci prototype on Xbox Kinect","ThreadAuthorFirstName":"Suresh kumar"}]
```

NOTE: I'm building this extension for a codeigniter application where i'm using phil sturgeon  codeigniter-restserver ( http://goo.gl/YOQFq )

Comment: Do not put `document.write` in a callback.  It won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Because the current page is at a different domain, jQuery is sending a JSONP request, which creates a `<script>` tag.

Your server is sending the response (to the `<script>` tag) as `application/json`, not `text/javascript`.

Comment: Thx Slaks, after making some changes now that warning has gone. Right now there is no error & no warning but, when i'm clicking on the extension icon nothing is happening. Just a blank box is coming...

Comment: @mi6: Either change your server to return JSONP (which would create a security hole) or change your code to make a normal AJAX request.

Comment: If i make normal AJAX request it's showing some "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error. 

Here is the code of normal AJAX request..

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://localhost/CI/index.php/welcome/chromeExtension",
   data: "json",
   success: function(data){
     //alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
     var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"json": data }');
     for (var i in obj.json) 
     {
      //alert(obj.json[i].ThreadID);
   document.write(obj.json[i].ThreadAuthorFirstName + " : " + obj.json[i].ThreadTitle );
   document.write("<br />");
  } 
   }
 });

Comment: @mi6: That's because you're in a normal page and not an extension.  You can either use JSONP (and beware of information disclosure) or run that code in the extension.

Comment: In my extension there are 3 files. 
* icon.png
* manifest.json
* popup.html

The plain AJAX code which i've shown above has used in this popup.html file and i'm executing the popup.html by clicking on the extension icon.

Comment: I don't know enough about Chrome extensions to answer that.